# Suggestions On How to Handle Facebook Login/Connect On Website for Preexisting Users

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I run a membership website, and on this site users can join for free.  They can also pay for an upgraded subscription.  Their login details are email/password.

I recently integrated facebook connect/login for this site.  On the login/signup page, I now have two new buttons: "Login with Facebook" & "Signup with Facebook" **(you can still sign in the "old" way, using email/password though)**

If a user clicks the "signup with facebook" button, a new account will be created using that persons facebook email address, and they're automatically logged in.  If an account already exists under that persons facebook email address, a message appears telling them they already have an account under that email address and to please sign in using the "login with facebook" button.

If a user clicks the "login with facebook" button, the script gets their facebook email address, checks the membership database on my site for an account that has a matching email address, and if one exists it logs them into that account.  If there is no account under that email address within my membership database, they're told that no account exists under [their facebook email] and to please sign up for one.

**Here is the core of my problem/question (explanation above was necessary though)**:
I thought that this was a perfectly good solution for integrating facebook connect/login, however I've had a few developers tell me that it is highly unexpected behavior for a user to click a "login with facebook" button and be told they're unable to be logged in, and to please signup first.  They've suggested that the best behavior would be that if they click the "login with facebook" button and no preexisting account can be located, that one should just be automatically created under that email address.

The reason I see an issue with this, is that I know for a fact I'll end up with plenty of people who will click the "login with facebook" button thinking they're going to be logged into their preexisting account, but will actually end up creating a NEW account because the email address on their facebook account and the email address they have within my membership site are two different email addresses.

So my question is *what do you think the best way to handle using facebook connect/login on my website is given the above situation?*

Comment: First of all, you should be aware that you will not even _get_ an email address for every user that logs in to your app – they might not have one on file with FB (if they signed up using their mobile), or for other reasons (such as that they did not verify it). I think the best way to go here, is if upon FB login you do not find an already existing account, alert the user to that fact, and ask them if they want to create a new account first – let them explicitly choose to do so by clicking a button or something. […]

Comment: At the same time(!), tell them that if they have an existing account on your site and want to “link” that to their Facebook account, they should log in to their existing account (via email & password) first, so that their FB account can be matched to it. (_If_ you get an email address from Facebook and it matches an existing account, you might want to join them automatically still … but probably best to alert users to the fact that this will happen somewhere in your help section/FAQ beforehand nevertheless.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe.  I am aware of the possibility of not getting email addresses, however for the sake of brevity and being concise, I left out the error handling bit(s).  That aside, thanks very much for your suggestion of alerting to the user no account exists and to ask them to explicitly choose to create a new one.  I think that is the perfect middle ground between what I have, and what some other developers had suggested.  Thank you!

Comment: OK, I made an answer out of those comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to go here, is if upon Facebook login you do not find an already existing account (matching by email address or the Facebook user id obtained on a previous FB login), alert the user to that fact and ask them first, if they want to create a new account – let them explicitly choose to do so by clicking a button or something.

At the same time, tell them that if they already have an existing account on your site and want to “link” that to their Facebook account, they should log in to their existing account (via email & password) first, so that their FB account can be matched to it.

If you get an email address from Facebook and it matches an existing account, you might want to join the accounts automatically – but making that an extra step, like “hey, we found an account with that email address already, do you want to link this existing account to this Facebook account?” would probably not hurt much either. (If you want to do it automatically, probably best to alert users to the fact that this will happen somewhere in your help section/FAQ beforehand nevertheless – so that’s there’s no surprises for anyone.)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I personally prefer your method, however perhaps having a separate sign up and login page might be best. This way, a user has multiple options to log in as well as sign up and it makes it more clear which is appropriate for them.